# Spring Security Configuration in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I am working on converting a *Spring 3* project to *Spring 4 + Spring Boot*. I don't know whether it is a right thing to do or not yet. I convert the *Spring Security XML* configuration to a *Java based configuration* as the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http.formLogin()
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/afterLogin")
            .loginPage("/profiles/lognin/form")
            .failureUrl("/accessDenied")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .regexMatchers("....")
            .hasRole("ROLE_USER")
            .antMatchers("....")
            .hasRole("ROLE_USER")
            //....
            ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder)
        throws Exception {
           authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(this.getDaoAuthenticationProvider());
}
   // ....
}
```

I get the *Spring Security* default login popup panel when I hit the home URL. It seem to me that the above configuration doesn't take effect, but the default *Spring Security* configuration in *Spring Boot* doesn't. If so, how to override the default one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer. I need to create a file called `application.properties` with the following line:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
```

and place this file under `src/main/resource`. That is it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your spring like that.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
                .csrf()
            .and()
                .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
            .and()
                .rememberMe()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/user")   // rest apiyi yaz.
                //.usernameParameter("username")
                //.passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                //.logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                //.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "CSRF-TOKEN")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/#/dashboard/home").permitAll()
            ;



}
```