# How to make spring-boot REST service with security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to add security to spring-boot REST project. I use own custom authntication with controller and DB, not basic, not OAuth.

Are there any good tutorials about how to add security to spring-boot REST project?

I use security config:

```
package com.example.control.api;

import com.example.control.api.shared.service.DatabaseAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/", "/greeting")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/authentication/authenticate")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        return new DatabaseAuthenticationProvider();
    };

    @Bean
    SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository(){
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

I'm using this controller to authenticate:

```
package com.example.control.api.authentication;

import com.example.control.api.shared.dao.IUserDAO;
import com.example.control.api.shared.domain.Employee;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/authentication")
public class AuthenticationController {

    @Autowired
    //@Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    SecurityContextRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    IUserDAO userDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity login(
            @RequestBody AuthenticationDataModel authData,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authData.getUsername(), authData.getPassword());
        try {
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            repository.saveContext(SecurityContextHolder.getContext(), request, response);
            return new ResponseEntity((Employee)auth.getDetails(), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Employee>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }


    }
}
```

And I got an error when request for method `login` of this controller:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot invoke saveContext on response org.springframework.security.web.firewall.FirewalledResponse@445f4cfa. You must use the HttpRequestResponseHolder.response after invoking loadContext
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:111)
    at com.example.control.api.authentication.AuthenticationController.login(AuthenticationController.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error message. In my case I was so concentrated on the Java configuration (I switched from xml) that I forgot to create a subclass of AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer like this:

```
public class SecurityWebInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

For further information you may refer to: http://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow this link
[Spring Security Configuration in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171265/spring-security-configuration-in-spring-boot)

You need to know three things

1. Add security rules from your xml/java/groovy configuration
2. Disable Default Spring security in Spring Boot project - You need to create or update a file called   application.properties with the following line:
   **security.basic.enabled=false**
   and place this file under src/main/resource
3. In case, if you want to use basic security, just add annotation to your java config - **@EnableWebSecurity**

Comment: I use REST controller for authenticate. Your solution don't work in my case. I added more info about realization in question. I hope you could help me.